# Error migrating to Entity Framework, the table is not updated

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I add a new field to the class `User` - `IdentiyUser`, after which I ran

```
add-migration [name]
```

This creates a migration file, but after executing `update-database` command, I get two errors.

I tried to delete the database and create it with its migration, the database is created, the column with my field is added, but the errors are the same

> Failed executing DbCommand (12ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text',  CommandTimeout='30']
> CREATE TABLE [AspNetRoles]
> (
> [Id] nvarchar(450) NOT NULL,
> [Name] nvarchar(256) NULL,
> [NormalizedName] nvarchar(256) NULL,
> [ConcurrencyStamp] nvarchar(max) NULL,
> CONSTRAINT [PK_AspNetRoles] PRIMARY KEY ([Id])
> );
>
> There is already an object named 'AspNetRoles' in the database.

Migration

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    migrationBuilder.RenameColumn(
            name: "Balance",
            table: "AspNetUsers",
            newName: "Age");
}

protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    migrationBuilder.RenameColumn(
            name: "Age",
            table: "AspNetUsers",
            newName: "Balance");
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the error occurs on this specific migration? Because this migration has nothing to do with AspNetRoles as indicated in the error message.

Comment: No, it always arises (

Comment: How many migrations do you have? and how long are they? I'm asking to see if it's possible to share them all.

Comment: At the moment, one, because I deleted the migration folder, it was not worth it?

Comment: There must be a migration file that includes creation code for `AspNetRoles` table which already exists in your database.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24169140/there-is-already-an-object-named-aspnetroles-in-the-database @pitten

Answer (score 3):

when you delete the migrations to create just one you should delete the database because the tables are created and you get that error. The faster solution in this case is delete all migrations folder and database and start all over.

Answer (score 0):

1. [Column(TypeName ="nvarchar(250)")] - Check the paranthese closing and Quotations(I rectified the error here)
2. Delete the Migration
3. Ad-Migration "InitialCreate"
4. Update-Database -verbose

Answer (score 0):

There is already an object named 'AspNetRoles' in the database. You must delete 'AspNetRoles' databese with connections and then
You must made update database again. if not again, make database name AspNetRoles1

Answer (score 0):

you have a duplicated object "AspNetRoles", you try to create table (object) with same name of an object who exist on Data Base already.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Why are you answering a 3,5 year old question? It was probably resolved 3,5 years ago.... You should check the dates of questions. Also: please check if nobody else has written the same answer before you.